# Only Display Current Month Data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, group-by

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy songs and my Index page organizes the data by Month. Everything works fine, But now I would like to strictly display the information for the current month. (In Our Case JUNE).

Currently I am able to list every month's data, but this can become a problem to display when million of songs are being bought throughout the year.

How Can I Only display the current Months Data?

**CONTROLLER**

```
def index
  @orders = Order.find(:all, :order => 'order_date, id')
end
```

**VIEW**

```
###How can i Only Display Current Month?
<% @orders.sort.group_by { |order| order.order_date.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, orders| %>
  <h3><%= month.strftime('%B') %> </h3>

  <% orders.group_by { |order| order.song.album.artist }.each do |artist, orders| %>
    <h4><%= artist.name %> </h4>

    <% orders.group_by { |order| order.song.album }.each do |album, orders| %>
      <h5><%= album.name %> </h5>

        <% orders.group_by { |order| order.song }.each do |song, orders| %>
          <p>(<%= orders.count %>) <%= song.title %> </p>
          <p><%= song.price %> </p>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Just change your controller query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? (in your controller)

```
@orders = Orders.where('created_at < ? and created_at > ?', Time.now.end_of_month, Time.now.beginning_of_month)
```